# Numbers between decimal number

Tags: rational-numbers, number-systems

So there is a question that says I can choose a number between $0.00001$ and $0.1$, but the problem is what exactly comes after $0.00001$?

Would it be $0.0001$, continued by $0.001$, $0.01$, $0.1$?

or

$0.00002,0.00003,0.00004,...$

I'm really confused :)

Comment: It does not really make a difference, but do you mean the real or the rational numbers ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no “next number” after a given real number because there is always another number between any two real numbers.

For example, the average of two numbers is always strictly between them.

Comment: so if i get to choose a number between 0.00001 and 0.1, would choosing 0.0001 a possible number?

Comment: Yes, that’s one possibility. It’s certainly true that 0.00001<0.0001<0.1

Comment: Nice explanation (+1), though I think you meant the average of two *distinct* numbers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Certainly. But given OP’s evident simplicity, I doubt it would occur to him to pick that particular nit. Let’s just assume I mean a set of real numbers with cardinality $2$. I didn’t want to add potentially confusing technical language when it’s clear what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Not only the real numbers , even the rational numbers form a dense set, that means that , given rational numbers $\ a,b\ $ with $\ a<b\ $ , there are infinite many rational numbers $\ c\ $ with $\ a<c<b\ $. You can , for example , choose $$c:=a+\frac{b-a}{k}$$ with some integer $\ k>1\ $ doing the job and already showing the existence of infinite many $\ c's\ $.